# How to Decode QRCode from WebCamera using Aforge.NET and ZXing.NET in C#

Tags: c#, zxing, aforge

I am trying to develop a WindowsForm Application which will use webcamera to detect QRCode and decode the message. For this I am using AForge.NET and ZXing.NET.

So far, I have been able to figure out how to decode the QRCode from an URI, but I want to detect the QRCode from webcamera, and decode it.

Below is the sample to my code.

```
public String Decode(Uri uri)
{
    Bitmap image;
    try
    {
        image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(uri.LocalPath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + uri);
    }

    using (image)
    {
        String text = "";
        LuminanceSource source = new BitmapLuminanceSource(image);

        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Result result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap);

        if (result != null)
        {
            text = result.Text;
            return text;
        }

        text = "Provided QR couldn't be read.";
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you'll need to capture the camera image and, then, call the decode library

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    private FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource;
    private Bitmap capturedImage;
    private String message = "";

    public FormQRCodeScanner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FormQRCodeScanner_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
        {
            comboBoxCameraSource.Items.Add(device.Name);
        }
        comboBoxCameraSource.SelectedIndex = 0;

        videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice();

        buttonStartStop.Text = "Start";
        buttonCapture.Enabled = false;
        buttonDecode.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void FormQRCodeScanner_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoSource.IsRunning)
        {
            videoSource.Stop();
        }
    }

    void videoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBoxSource.Image = image;
    }

    private void buttonStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoSource.IsRunning)
        {
            videoSource.Stop();
            pictureBoxSource.Image = null;
            pictureBoxCaptured.Image = null;
            pictureBoxSource.Invalidate();
            pictureBoxCaptured.Invalidate();

            buttonStartStop.Text = "Start";
            buttonCapture.Enabled = false;
            buttonDecode.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[comboBoxCameraSource.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);
            videoSource.Start();

            buttonStartStop.Text = "Stop";
            buttonCapture.Enabled = true;
            buttonDecode.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void buttonCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (videoSource.IsRunning)
        {
            pictureBoxCaptured.Image = (Bitmap)pictureBoxSource.Image.Clone();
            capturedImage = (Bitmap)pictureBoxCaptured.Image;
        }
    }

    private void buttonDecode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (capturedImage != null)
        {
            ExtractQRCodeMessageFromImage(capturedImage);
            richTextBoxMessage.Text = message;
            richTextBoxMessage.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }

    private string ExtractQRCodeMessageFromImage(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        try
        {
            BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader
                (null, newbitmap => new BitmapLuminanceSource(bitmap), luminance => new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(luminance));

            reader.AutoRotate = true;
            reader.TryInverted = true;
            reader.Options = new DecodingOptions { TryHarder = true };

            var result = reader.Decode(bitmap);

            if (result != null)
            {
                message = result.Text;
                return message;
            }
            else
            {
                message = "QRCode couldn't be decoded.";
                return message;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = "QRCode couldn't be detected.";
            return message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**For this you should install these packages
Install-Package AForge
Install-Package AForge.Video
Install-Package AForge.Video.DirectShow
Install-Package ZXing.Net

you can watch this video for more help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wcoy0Gwxr50**




    using System.IO;
    using AForge;
    using AForge.Video;
    using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
    using ZXing;
    using ZXing.Aztec;


      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
                foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(Device.Name);
                }

                comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
                FinalFrame.Start();

            }

            private void FinalFrame_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            }

            private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                BarcodeReader Reader = new BarcodeReader();
                Result result = Reader.Decode((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
                try
                {
                    string decoded = result.ToString().Trim();
                    if (decoded != "")
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();
                        MessageBox.Show(decoded);
                        Form2 form = new Form2();
                        form.Show();
                        this.Hide();

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }

            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();
            }

            private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
            {
                if (FinalFrame.IsRunning == true)
                {
                    FinalFrame.Stop();
                }
            }
```